# Ignore LaTeX errors with Sphinx LaTeXBuilder while building documentation PDFs

Tags: pdf, latex, python-sphinx, pdflatex, read-the-docs

In my project, I am building a PDF version of my documentation with Sphinx's LaTeXBuilder where I have several files and extensions that can potentially cause problems with the output. The project is hosted on Read the Docs, which fails to build a PDF with this error log:

```
! LaTeX Error: Too deeply nested.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.8916 \begin{itemize}
```

and this is the corresponding list in the `.tex` file

```
\begin{itemize}
\item {} 
\sphinxAtStartPar
”current” (default) : the current is explicity supplied

\item {} 
\sphinxAtStartPar
”voltage”/”power”/”resistance” : solve an algebraic equation for                     current such that voltage/power/resistance is correct

\item {} 
\sphinxAtStartPar
”differential power”/”differential resistance” : solve a                     differential equation for the power or resistance

\item {} 
\sphinxAtStartPar
”CCCV”: a special implementation of the common constant\sphinxhyphen{}current                     constant\sphinxhyphen{}voltage charging protocol, via an ODE for the current

\item {} 
\sphinxAtStartPar
callable : if a callable is given as this option, the function                     defines the residual of an algebraic equation. The applied current                     will be solved for such that the algebraic constraint is satisfied.

\end{itemize}

\end{description}

\end{itemize}
```

which is causing a nested list and as such cannot be handled for more than four nestings as I have been made aware.

I am running `latexmk` in force mode with this command:

```
latexmk -r latexmkrc -pdf -f -dvi- -ps- -jobname=myproject -interaction=nonstopmode
```

to avoid the issue. This builds my PDF documentation correctly as required and ignores all other LaTeX warnings, but the program still ends with an error code 1 due to the LaTeX error, which fails the workflow for me. Is there a way to ignore this error and not return a non-zero error code, perhaps through the options or configuration values for LaTeX output inside `conf.py`, because the PDF is working and can be opened without issues? In my case it would be better to solve the problem with Sphinx itself, rather than using a custom build command on Read the Docs.

The `Latexmk` error log at the end of the output is

```
Output written on myproject.pdf (195 pages, 781197 bytes).
Transcript written on myproject.log.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'myproject.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'myproject.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'myproject.log'
Latexmk: Index file 'myproject.idx' was written
Latexmk: Missing input file 'myproject.toc' (or dependence on it) from following:
  No file myproject.toc.
Latexmk: Missing input file 'myproject.ind' (or dependence on it) from following:
  No file myproject.ind.
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'myproject.pdf'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'myproject.log' and/or above output for details

Latexmk: If appropriate, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
make: *** [myproject.pdf] Error 12
```

which does not make sense, because I am already using the `-f` command-line flag. Alternatively, if there is a way to provide the built `myproject.PDF` file to Read the Docs (might be through https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/build-customization.html#where-to-put-files) even if it is through a build command, it would fix my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the auto-generation of PDF on Read the Docs by using the `formats` configuration key (see https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html#formats)

After that, you can build the PDF as you want using `build.jobs` configuration key (https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html#build-jobs) and saving the final PDF file under `$READTHEDOCS_OUTPUT/pdf` directory. Here an example:

```yaml
version: 2

build:
  os: "ubuntu-22.04"
  tools:
    python: "3.11"
  jobs:
    post_build:
      # Create the directory where to put the files
      - mkdir --parents $READTHEDOCS_OUTPUT/pdf
      # Generate the PDF here as you want
      # and copy the resulting PDF file to the correct path
      - cp "<your-pdf-file>.pdf" $READTHEDOCS_OUTPUT/pdf/$READTHEDOCS_PROJECT.pdf


# Disable PDF format
formats: []
```